# Pair CSV::Row objects

Tags: ruby, arrays, loops, csv, hash

I ended up with the array of 10 CSV::Row objects. Now I want to pair them as there is 2 of every object with the same name. Now I know how to do this, long way of multiple loops and its just not elegant. Anyone any quick 1-2 liner to do this?

So this is the array:

```
[#<CSV::Row "name":"eee.xxx" "time":"2014-10-31T15:35:14+00:00" "records":"98">,
 #<CSV::Row "name":"eee.yyy" "time":"2014-10-31T15:35:30+00:00" "records":"207">,
 #<CSV::Row "name":"sss.zzz" "time":"2014-10-31T15:35:44+00:00" "records":"205">,
 #<CSV::Row "name":"sss.qqq" "time":"2014-10-31T15:35:59+00:00" "records":"220">,
 #<CSV::Row "name":"sss.www" "time":"2014-10-31T15:36:15+00:00" "records":"220">,
 #<CSV::Row "name":"eee.xxx" "time":"2014-10-31T15:36:30+00:00" "records":"99">,
 #<CSV::Row "name":"eee.yyy" "time":"2014-10-31T15:36:42+00:00" "records":"210">,
 #<CSV::Row "name":"sss.zzz" "time":"2014-10-31T15:36:57+00:00" "records":"225">,
 #<CSV::Row "name":"sss.qqq" "time":"2014-10-31T15:37:12+00:00" "records":"210">,
 #<CSV::Row "name":"sss.www" "time":"2014-10-31T15:37:25+00:00" "records":"230">]
```

What I would like to end up with something like this hash:

```
{"eee.xxx" => [98,99],
 "eee.yyy" => [207,210],
 "sss.zzz" => [205,225],
 "sss.qqq" => [220,210],
 "sss.www" => [220,203]}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes do as below :-

```
hash = array.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }) do |row,hsh| 
  hsh[row['name']] << row['records']
end
```

Look at the method [`CSV::Row#[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV/Row.html#method-i-5B-5D), and [`new {|hash, key| block } → new_hash`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Hash.html#method-c-new) methods.

Another way is :-

```
hash = array.each_with_object({}) do |row,hsh| 
  (hsh[row['name']] ||= []) << row['records']
end
```